# How to define x, y axis in CSS3 for different screen resolutions

Tags: css, css-transitions

So here is the problem, I am using CSS3 transform:translate(x, y) to transitions objects from the left side of the screen to the right. (x axis) The problem is depending on the screen resolutions, these objects are flying off the screen. According to what I've found I can use percentages to define the coordinates but upon using them, they seem to act the same as if I used pixel measurement. Is this possible only using css3 or will I have to implement this with Javascript of media queries?

ps, its treating 1400% as 1400px, I've tried with em's as well.

```
$(window).load(function() {


     $('#second').css({
         webkitTransform : 'translate(1400%,0)',
     mozTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     msTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     oTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transition: 'all 1.25s ease-in-out'


     });


$('#first').css({
         webkitTransform : 'translate(1400%,0)',
     mozTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     msTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     oTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transition: 'all 1.75s ease-in-out'

     });

$('#third').css({
     webkitTransform : 'translate(1400%,0)',
     mozTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     msTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     oTransform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transform : 'translate(1400%, 0)',
     transition: 'all .75s ease-in-out'


     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position them absolutely and then transition on `left` and `margin-left`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/b3hGy/)

```
#trans {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00F;
    -moz-transition:all 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
    transition:all 2s ease;
}

#trans.toggle {
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Your particular solution isn't working because you're just moving them 1400% to the right which is the same as `14 * width`.

To change it on page load, put the class in the document ready.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/xLn9B/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#trans').addClass('toggle');
});
```

Comment: I need it tied to the page load. With this option I need to use addClass instead of using a click event.

Comment: not sure if that's still correct, but using left and margin might be less performant than using the translate function, especially on slower mobile devices